# Locating a dependent Hotfix (80451)

Tags: 2011, cme, publishing

We are currently applying hotfixes to a new build of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1+HR1 and have come across Hotfix CME_2011.1.1.83722

This hotfix *fixes problem: Unpublishing a page shows also shows the that it will unpublish the DCPs on the page*

Within the description of this hotfix it states:

> Dependencies: 80451

We've not been successful in locating this on sdltridionworld (we've also confirmed it's not part of *Hotfix rollup SDL Tridion 2011 SP1-1*) and wondered if anyone has applied this fix and located the dependent hotfix 80451?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to contact Customer Support for this one. It is not a question that the community can answer, just the SDL Tridion folks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Frank suggests, we have approached SDL Tridion Support for this. We just wanted to check it wasn't tucked away somewhere we'd missed.

If an admin wants to remove this question It's fine. But it may save someone else checking up later.

Comment: Not sure on this hotfix, but not all of them are on SDL Tridion World since they don't always apply to all customers. Support is definitely the way to go.